# should I use Navigator or View State?

Tags: apache-flex, view, viewstate

Hi I want to create an application has this sort of function:
http://looklet.com/create
In this application when you click the button (or some tilelist) on the right the model on the left update accordingly. I wonder how they achieve this. Originally i think it's some sort of image-only pop-up window but then pop-up window seems to update the entire view. 
Then I think it might be only change view state, but then I still confused how it can be done using view state.

Flex expert please give me some hint !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like transparent images drawn on Canvas. Each piece must have predefined offset and draw order.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just images placed on one or more Canvas, with the z-order controlled for depth.

The body stays the same, so shirts probably have their own placement properties, as do skirts, underwear, hosiery, etc. as well as backgrounds, faces, etc.